# tcp client in c that send and listens : concept

Tags: c, tcp, client

I'm looking into making a tcp client in C.
But before I start I would like some advise from you.

The client is for controlling lights and other devices.

With this client I will need to send commands, but I can also receive events when a light is turned off by someone.

Just sending commands with sockets is no problem.
But at the same time I have to read for incoming packages.

How is this best solved?
Do I need to use threads or can I solve this with something like libevent?

How do most people implement something like this?

This library should be as portable as possible. (linux, unix, windows, ...)

(I'm not looking for code, but just a best approach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BSD sockets are bidirectional, and you can check if your socket has an incoming data or not by select(2)

- http://rhoden.id.au/doc/sockets2.html
- or search for "socket select" in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=socket+select

IMHO using libevent is too much for your purpose.  It's nice but you have long way to go to realize its power.  Actually libevent is a wrapper for select(2) or its improved successor epoll(2) etc.

Comment: Can I still send commands during a select? I user must be able to control a light at all time. (using a GUI or web interface or something) I have to wait for user input and incoming data at the same time.

Comment: select(2) takes a parameter for timeout.  If you're not working for the gaming industry, timeout of 100 ms will suffice.  (ie. the user need to wait for at most 100 ms for his input to be processed.)

Comment: thanks, I think I'll try select(2) first and if it works fine I'll try to improve it with libuv

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to have two connections, one for sending command, one for getting respond from server when someone turns off light, most of time two conns are sleep. if you only create one connection, you have to query light status every xx ms, most of time it wastes bandwidth. if your app is not serious, server can use UDP to notify client when the light is turned off by someone, which solution only needs one live TCP connection.

Comment: I just send a tcp command that I would like to receive an update every time the light changes. The server than sends a package for each change. I can only make one connection from the same pc. (I didn't wrote the server)